# How to create a 2 dimensional object with string index and loop through results

Tags: javascript

I have a syntax issue. I've been looking through hundreds of posts about multidimensional objects and arrays and can't find what I'm looking for. I basically need to populate a database with a bunch of presets and am looking for a way to set those in an array (or 2d object) so I can loop through them and insert them to the database.

The data is a simple list of objects and their accessories. i.e:

```
Door ->   Handle
          Letterbox
          Cat Flap
          Hinges
          Lock
Window -> Sill
          Frame
          Lock
          Handle
```

etc.

I then want a function like this (where "items" is the object that holds all the data) that loops through the results and inserts items and accessories:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    insertItem(item,'','Object');

    for (var b = 0; b < item.length; b++) {
        var accessory = item[b];
        insertItem(item,accessory,'Accessory');
    }
}
```

My question is, how would i put my data into an object and would my looping function work to cycle through the data?

Comment: Is the question about structuring the data or about how to access it (or both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use an object literal?

```
var house = new Object();
    house = {
        "door" : {
            "handle" : true,
            "letterbox" : true,
            "catFlap" : true,
            "hinges" : true,
            "lock" : true
        },
        "window" : {
            "sill" : true,
            "frame" : true,
            "lock" : true,
            "handle" : true
        }
    };
```

Then you can access it with a `for...in` loop

```
for(var item in house){
    for(var accessory in house[item]){
        if(house[item][accessory]){ //announce what was found
            alert(accessory); 
        }
        house[item][accessory] = false; //take accessory away
        house[item].newAccessory = true; //Add an accessory
    }
}
```

Comment: `var house = new Object();` is unnecessary if you use an object literal in the next line.

Comment: That is true, but I decided to be verbose considering it didn't appear that he knew what an object literal was at all.

Comment: But you are just overwriting the initial value of the variable with your second assignment. If you want to demonstrate how to assign `5` to a variable, would you write `var num = 0; num = 5;`? I'd say that's more confusing than helpful.

Comment: I was trying to make it clear to him that house is an Object and not an Array. Considering that `int something = {1,2,3};` is notation for an array declaration in Java (and we know how people like to get confused), I didn't want him to mistake curly braces for array notation here. I don't know what his background is and just wanted to be as clear as possible about what `house` actually is, I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I get the principal, thanks but your example returned no results. adding in a console.log(item) and console.log(accessory) in the relevant places did show me the two items but no accessories... Sorry to be thick, I'm totally new to javascript. My background is in php.

Comment: Sorry about that! I had a typo in the nested `for...in` loop. I fixed it. Here is a fiddle that has a bunch of `console.log()`'s in it to help you understand how things work. http://jsfiddle.net/wrexroad/7KuYw/6/